# How to maintain column names while pivoting data, with no aggregation and not using artificial index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe like this, which has about 40 unique in the `key` column and some of them are integer. I do not want anything aggregated if possible
:

```
hash  ft  timestamp               id   key   value
1ab   1   2022-01-02 12:21:11     1    aaa   121289
1ab   1   2022-01-02 12:21:11     1    bbb   13ADF
1ab   1   2022-01-02 12:21:11     2    aaa   13ADH
1ab   1   2022-01-02 12:21:11     2    bbb   13ADH
2ab   2   2022-01-02 12:21:11     3    aaa   121382
2ab   2   2022-01-02 12:21:11     3    bbb   121381
2ab   2   2022-01-02 12:21:11     3    ccc   121389
```

I am trying to pivot the data only on 2 on columns `key` and `value` while keeping the remaining same columns and index. Example:

[image]

When I run below code, the column names take on grouped values with columnname being  for the following columns `id, ft, value`. One of the actual column names, with parentheses : `('id', '1', '121289')` and I am forced to select an index, which I dont want do.

Code:
`df.pivot_table(index='hash',columns=['ft','key'])`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, that I cant use the `value` column for `values`. I get an empty dataframe:

```
df.pivot_table(index='hash',columns=['ft','key'], values='value')
```

Comment: try `pivot` instead, since there is no aggregation involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, using [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
(df.pivot(index=['hash', 'ft', 'id', 'timestamp'],
          columns=['key'], values='value')
 .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
  hash  ft  id            timestamp     aaa     bbb     ccc
0  1ab   1   1  2022-01-02 12:21:11  121289   13ADF     NaN
1  1ab   1   2  2022-01-02 12:21:11   13ADH   13ADH     NaN
2  2ab   2   3  2022-01-02 12:21:11  121382  121381  121389
```

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {'hash': {0: '1ab',
  1: '1ab',
  2: '1ab',
  3: '1ab',
  4: '2ab',
  5: '2ab',
  6: '2ab'},
 'ft': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2},
 'timestamp': {0: '2022-01-02 12:21:11',
  1: '2022-01-02 12:21:11',
  2: '2022-01-02 12:21:11',
  3: '2022-01-02 12:21:11',
  4: '2022-01-02 12:21:11',
  5: '2022-01-02 12:21:11',
  6: '2022-01-02 12:21:11'},
 'id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 3},
 'key': {0: 'aaa', 1: 'bbb', 2: 'aaa', 3: 'bbb', 4: 'aaa', 5: 'bbb', 6: 'ccc'},
 'value': {0: '121289',
  1: '13ADF',
  2: '13ADH',
  3: '13ADH',
  4: '121382',
  5: '121381',
  6: '121389'}}
)
```

**EDIT**

To overcome an error reported below, in a comment, by the OP, the OP himself suggests the following solution:

```
(pd.pivot_table(df,index=['hash','ft', 'id'] ,
                columns = ['key'] , 
                values = "value", aggfunc='sum')
 .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

Comment: thank you so much. I am still getting an error `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`. I have reset the index as well. I have also confirmed dropping dupes.

Comment: Welcome, @RustyShackleford! Please, try with the data I used, which I have just added to my answer.

Comment: I got this to work. Its 95% percent your answer modified. If you want to change your answer, happy to accept it has the answer.  

`pd.pivot_table(df,index=['hash','ft', 'id']
                        ,columns = ['key']
                        , values = "value",aggfunc='sum').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: Great that you have fixed the problem, @RustyShackleford! I have just edited my answer by adding your code.